# Jquery assign input value but empty when form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

I  have a form as shown below.

```
<form id="addressform">
 <input asp-for="City" id="edtCity" class="form-control k-textbox" maxlength="60" />
</form>
<input type="text" id="hiddenCity" value="" />
```

Assign `hiddenCity` input value as shown below and works fine

```
$('#hiddenCity').val(addressResult[2]);
```

I have jquery to assign `hiddenCity` textbox value to `edtCity` text-box inside the form this also works

```
$('#edtCity').val($('#hiddenCity').val())
```

Jquery assign the value i can see the value assigned but `edtCity` textbox null when submit. when i type the value into the textbox it works fine

Comment: Show the javascript function as well

Comment: @Chilarai i added the fucntion

Comment: Please share your model design.Did you mean when you submit the form,the action could not get the `edtCity` textbox value?

Comment: @Rena yes thats what happening, but when i type the value into the textbox it works fine

Comment: Why is the `hiddenCity` `input` outside of the form? Only form elements within a form are submitted when the form is submitted. Also your input elements do not have `name` attribute values.

Comment: It could work well in my project.I suggest that you could share your controller action and the whole razor view.

Comment: @PeterKA i tried it inside and outside but doesn't change anything

Comment: @Rena why is it working when i type the value into text-box?

Comment: There is no doubt it work when you type the value.Both of the two ways could work for me.I think you may have issue with your razor view or others.So provide more code would be helpful. Did your `edtCity` filled with value when you using jquery?

Comment: @Rena Yes `edtCity` filled when using jquery, also i see this behavior after jquery filled the edtCity if i type space at the end and submit  works fine the problem is if i submit after jquery filled the value it submit null

Comment: @Rena  adding`.change()` solves my problem `$('#edtCity').val($('#hiddenCity').val()).change()` Thanks for your help

Comment: well, the controls have to be inside the form - end of story - fix that. and you don't have any runat="server" tags for those  controls - without that then code behind can't see nor use or check or modify the values of those controls in code behind (your vb code).